# HTTP request works with cURL but gets CORS response when made in browser with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cors

When I access the typeform API via browser using $.get or superagent or request or axios, I get the error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

However, when I user cURL or HTTPIE or Postman to make the same request, it is successful everytime. How to solve this behaviour and how to implement the client version?

Comment: Browsers aren't allowed to make cross-domain AJAX requests unless the server specifically allows it. Servers are not restricted.

Comment: you can disable cors security in browsers for dev purposes.  Just google it.

Answer (score 5):

CORS is enforced client side by your browser. If you are not making the request with a browser CORS is not enforced.

Answer (score 1):

CORS error can be manipulated through htaccess easily.

Add this to your .htaccess file: (add more file extensions as you need)

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I doubt OP has the rights to modify the typeform API's configs.